# html input text "password box" and button to check if a password is correct to display "OK" or "ERROR"

Tags: javascript, html

First semester WEB student here. Introduced to JavaScript at the end of this semester. Professor does not go into any type of detail. I have searched on W3schools and google for help. In HTML, I am to create an input text box (type="text") and a button (type="button") there is no . This part was simple.

The part I am not understanding is the JavaScript. 
The text box should get focus when the page loads. I am to add JS inside the HTML page that includes a JS comment (not an html comment) and solves the tasks below:
Code an event that will execute when the user clicks the button. 
If the user enters the correct password, display "OK" on the page else display "ERROR" for an incorrect password code another button that if clicked. The fontSize of the body is changed to 30px.

Now... I realize this should be a simple project, and I SHOULD be able to go to my professor with questions, but it is an online class and he just blows me off when I ask for help. I don't even know what else to search for this. W3schools has nothing similar. Please help. I just don't get it. I DO NOT want this done for me. It is pointless to just add someone else's code into my project and not learn something I will need in the future. I am looking for some resources to help me better understand the parts of this project I am struggling with. Thank you!

W3schools
google searches

```
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input id="password" type="text" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Run" onclick="passcheck()" />
<p id="result">
  result:
</p>
```

Comment: Look for some tutorials on getting and setting values in form controls (`<input>, <select>,<textarea>` etc). Also tutorials on form control events

Comment: Do you have a specific question? We can't do your homework for you, but if there is a specific think you need help with then we can take a look. Otherwise, as charlie said, look for some basic JS tutorials, they're everywhere on the Internet.

Comment: I need pointed in the right direction for some tutorials etc. I don't want the homework done for me. This was thrown in our laps without any type of direction from the professor. There were multiple discussions posted with the same issues I am having and the Professor's answer was usually " i dont know" I won't learn this without doing it for myself. I am sorry that my question came off as asking for the answers. I will edit now.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stay as far away from W3 Schools as you can. Just about all professionals know that, despite their great SEO results, the information they provide is often incomplete, out of date, misguided, or flat out wrong. Instead, use the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn), which is well-known as an authoritative source. And, if your instructor is recommending W3 Schools, it is an indication that he/she is not very knowledgeable about the subject matter he/she is teaching.

Comment: What it seems that you are looking for is an introduction to events and event handling, which you can learn about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: I will check out the Mozilla site you suggested. Thank you guys for giving me a little direction here. It would be nice to get this help from the Professor...

Comment: I can only second that w3schools is seldom helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<body>
<div>
  Password: 
  <input id="password" type="text" />
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Run" onclick="passcheck()" />
</div>
Result: <span id="result"/>
<script>

function passcheck() {
  const resultRef = document.getElementById('result');
  const inputRef = document.getElementById('password');

  /* You can pass any other condition 
     for checking the validity of the password
     instead of inputRef.value.length >= 6
  */
  const resultText = inputRef.value.length >= 6 ? 'OK' : 'ERROR';

  resultRef.innerHTML = resultText;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Besides it's better to use the type="password" for better usability
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Just pass all the JS tutorial on w3schools
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp

Hope it will help you)

Comment: Everywhere I am reading says the same thing type="password" but the Professor specifically said to use type="text" which I really do not understand why. thank you for your help.

Comment: We have certain expectations of questions here at Stack Overflow and some of those expectations are the the OP will do their research ahead of time and make an attempt at a solution of their own before posting. If we provide answers to questions that don't meet those standards, we just encourage more poor questions. That's why we provided comments, rather than answers above.

Comment: Also, see my comment below the question as to why it's not a good idea to reference W3 Schools as a resource.

Comment: Hi Scott, I should disagree, w3schools is great for the beginners, especially HTML and CSS course. MDN is also great, but it's further reading. That's only my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the JavaScript world!

As much I have understood, there are two things you want to do.
1) focusing an input on load
2) do validation on button click
3) changing of font size using JavaScript

First, to focus any input element on load in JavaScript, we need to fetch that element and then we can simply call tue focus function of JavaScript.

```
<script>
   document.getElementById(“password”).focus();
</script>
```

In the above given code, we are fetching any element(input) by getElementById and then setting it be focused by calling focus() function.

Second, again you have to get that password element inside your function and get its value and do some validation.

```
<script>
     function passcheck(){
        var password= document.getElementById(“password”).value;

         if(password == ‘your password’){
            alert(“Ok”);
        }else{
            alert(“invalid password”);
         }
     }
</script>
```

In the above code, the value is an property of element and      its the actual value you type in your input(password).

Third, you can create function like changeFont() and do your changes.

```
<script>  
    function changeFont(){
        document.getElementById(“your element id”).fontSize=     “30px”
     }
</script>
```

Final JavaScript code :

```
<script> 
document.getElementById(“password”).focus();


function passcheck(){
        var password= document.getElementById(“password”).value;

         if(password == ‘your password’){
            alert(“Ok”);
        }else{
            alert(“invalid password”);
         }
     }

 function changeFont(){
   document.getElementById(“your element id”).fontSize= “30px”
 }
</script>
```

If you want to learn more about JavaScript, then visit [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/JS)

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the detailed explanation. What I have coded already is pretty close to what you posted. Being new to this language I was missing a few { } here and there and some minor details. I really appreciate that you explained what each bit did, not just what the answer is. this really helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: And yes, welcome aboard mate! I would also suggest you go to though w3school site, and learn more about JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: While your answer is well-explained, we have certain expectations of questions here at Stack Overflow and some of those expectations are the the OP will do their research ahead of time and make an attempt at a solution of their own before posting. If we provide answers to questions that don't meet those standards, we just encourage more poor questions. That's why we provided comments, rather than answers above.

Comment: He did exactly what a tutorial would have done. I have ZERO experience with Javascript, He explained what he was doing for what reason. I have searched through everything that was suggested to me and I still did not understand. Bharat did far more to help me than my professor did. his code did not 100% fixe my problem, but with a little more searching and reading online after the bit he explained to me it made more sense and I was able to grasp the concept a little better. My assignment was given like this... Use visual studio to code javascript, with no prior knowledge. GO!

Comment: @ScottMarcus all I meant to guide him, not to disrespect or not follow any standards of stackoverflow. All I did is to guide him in the right direction.

Comment: @chonkypot No one is denying that the answer was helpful to you. That's not the point of my comment. You say he did exactly what a tutorial would have done, but Stack Overflow isn't meant to be a tutorial site. That's not what our mission is. SO is meant to be a place to come and ask a question after you've done all your research and tutorials and have actually made an attempt at a solution and still have a ***specific*** problem/question. It's unfortunate that your class is being taught so poorly, but SO isn't the place for your kind of question. The MDN links I provided will help.

Comment: @BharatChoudhary Yes, it's clear that you just wanted to help and that's great, but SO isn't a tutorial site and there are pretty clear guidelines on [what kinds of questions are appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [how we should answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)(including when not to answer). If we answer questions that are off-topic for our site, we're going to attract more off-topic questions. So, with these, we typically just provide a short comment.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Noted with apologies.